# Identify Circle vs Triangle Using Tensorflow on Array of Points

Tags: python, tensorflow, coordinates, shapes

I have many sets of xy coordinate that form the shape of either a triangle or circle. Is it possible to form a predictive model to predict what shape is formed by an array of points? I have been using Tensorflow to create predictive models but I am unsure how I would feed it large arrays of xy coordinates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is difficult to deal with variable-length input data, but if you make it fixed-length by random sampling, etc., you can simply put it in a linear layer. However, if I were you, I would plot the xy coordinates on an image and solve it as an image classification or image detection. It is much easier that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ken, I will look into image recognition for this problem. I’m pretty new to ML and assumed that a set of xy points would mean fewer data points and less computation than a whole image of pixels but there is that issue of variable length data with the former

Comment: The problem with using an array of coordinates is that the relationship between the coordinates is unknown; coordinates that are adjacent in 2D space may be completely far apart in the array. Because of this, you will end up calculating for every relationship (combination) of coordinates (which is what linear layers do). On the other hand, image recognition (convolution layers) can greatly reduce this by calculating only nearby pixels. Of course, it depends on the number of coordinates, image size, etc., but image recognition is likely to be faster.